# Django Class Based Views and Queries

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am attempting to filter for a single object, more specifically, today's entry. I then want to take that query and display the result within the template. No matter what I do I can't seem to get the filter to display anything in the template. I am not sure whether I need the query to be written within the view, the model, or both. My familiarity with Django querying is pretty light. A great resource on this topic would be extremely helpful as well.

I'm semi-new to Django, so any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

**models.py**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,)
    euros = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=900, blank=True, null=True)
    euros_sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    xrate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    dollars_sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    daily_savings_dollars = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('argent:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**views.py:**

```
    class IndexView(generic.ListView):
        template_name = 'argent/index.html'
        context_object_name = 'object_list'
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        filter = Entry.objects.filter(date=today_date)
        print(filter)


    class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
        model = Entry
        template_name = 'argent/detail.html'


    class EntryCreate(CreateView):
        form_class = EntryForm
        template_name = 'argent/entry_form.html'

        def form_valid(self, form):
            return super(EntryCreate, self).form_valid(form)


    class EntryUpdate(UpdateView):
        model = Entry
        form_class = EntryForm
        template_name = 'argent/entry_form.html'

        def form_valid(self, form):
            return super(EntryUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

> Note1: When I print "filter =" I get the correct object returned in the console.
>
> Note2: I am using my "queryset =" further down my template and it works
>   perfectly fine.

**template(index.html):**

```
<div class="container" style="font-family: 'Dosis', serif;">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background: #ebebeb">

        {% for Entry in filter %}

        <h1>Today's Spending</h1>
        <div class="container container-fluid" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px; font-family: 'Dosis', serif; color: white;">
        <div class="container container-fluid">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" style="font-size: large; color: #337ab7; font-weight: bold">{{ first.date }}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="color: #337ab7; font-weight: bold">Receipts:</td>
                    <td style="color: #FF6F18;"> {{ first.euros }} </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="color: #337ab7; font-weight: bold">Total Euros Spent:</td>
                    <td style="color: #FF6F18;">€{{first.euros_sum}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="color: #337ab7; font-weight: bold">Total Dollars Spent:</td>
                    <td style="color: #FF6F18;">${{first.dollars_sum}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="color: #337ab7; font-weight: bold">Exchange Rate:</td>
                    <td style="color: #FF6F18;">{{ first.xrate }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="color: #337ab7; font-weight: bold">Daily Savings:</td>

                    <td style="color: #FF6F18;">
                        {% if last.daily_savings_dollars > 0 %}
                        <div class="NegativeSavings" style="font-weight: bold">-
                        {% else %}
                        <div class="PositiveSavings" style="font-weight: bold">+
                        ${{ first.daily_savings_dollars }}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
<div class="container container-fluid" style="font-family:'Dosis', serif">

    <!-- Entry List -->
    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px">
        <div>
            &nbsp
        </div>
        {% if object_list %}
            {% for Entry in object_list %}
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: #ebebeb"; >
                        <a href="{% url 'argent:detail' Entry.id %}">
                            <h3 align="center" style="font-weight: bold">{{ Entry.date }}</h3>
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 align="center" style="color: #FF6F18">€{{ Entry.euros_sum }}
                            <!-- View Details -->
                            <a href="{% url 'argent:detail' Entry.id %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-lg">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button></a>

                            <!-- Update -->
                            <a href="{% url 'argent:entry-update' Entry.id %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-lg" style="padding: 0%">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button></a></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't do any db interaction at module level. You should override [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) (for what will be passed as `object_list` to the template) and [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) if you want additional stuff in your template context like the filtered queryset:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'argent/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'object_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Entry.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['filter'] = Entry.objects.filter(date=timezone.datetime.today())
        return ctx
```

The django documentation [`in general`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/) and its [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) section in particular are a good starting point. The [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) is worth completing, as well.

Comment: Thank you! Using this I was able to post the single object within the template using {% for ctx in filter %}. And thanks for the learning material.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your view to pass one of the querysets in as a context.

```
   class IndexView(generic.ListView):
       template_name = 'argent/index.html'
       context_object_name = 'object_list'
      #queryset = Entry.objects.all() use the get_queryset method to get this
      #filter = Entry.objects.filter(date=today_date)  add this using the get_context_data method

       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
           context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
           context.update({
           'filter': Entry.objects.filter(date=today_date),
           })
           return context

       def get_queryset(self):
           return  Entry.objects.all()
```